# TypeScript Compiling Twice when saving .ts files

Tags: typescript, angular, atom-editor

I am new to typescript and I am running across a problem compiling.  So the problem I am having is that when I save my .ts files they are compiled twice and in two different locations.

My current file structure is:

```
-app

  |-css (all css files)

  |-html (all html files)

  |-js (all js files)

  |-ts (all ts files)
```

When I save my .ts files they are compiled and placed in the js folder but then a set of new folders is created in the format:

```
-app

  |-...

  |-js (all js files)

    |-app

      |-ts (all js files [that were saved ts files])
  |-...
```

I have been looking around for anyone with a similar problem but couldn't find anything.  My package.json file and tsconfig.json files are as follows:

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "d3": "^4.1.1",
    "d3tip": "0.5.0",
    "d3-tip": "0.6.7",
    "d3-tooltip": "0.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "app/js",
    "rootDir": "app/ts"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:  Still having this problem.  --Not Resolved --07/28/2016--**

Comment: app/ts is where the ts files are

Comment: you said the compilation produces files in two different locations, what are they?

Comment: it create the js files in app/js and app/js/app/ts  (also the paths /app and /app/ts are added to app/js/... as they weren't there prior)

Comment: try removing `"outDir": "app/js",`

Comment: Then the output files would be compiled to /app/ts and I want them in the /app/js folder to keep them seperate

Comment: change from `"rootDir": "app/ts"` to `"rootDir": "app/js"`

Comment: you have a gulpfile or something like that?

Comment: changing the rootDir to "app/js" doesn't work as it doesn't then know where the ts files are (like in app/ts)

Comment: and @Batavia no I do not have a gulpfile

Comment: has anyone come across this same problem or does anyone have a fix/input for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I thought a few weeks back that I solved this issue but I was wrong.  HOWEVER, I have now found the solution.

The problem was actually not with the location of where my js files were being compiled.  The js files were going to the correct location during the first compile, BUT I am using the Atom IDE and atom-typescript has a default that it compiles the files when they are saved in the Atom-editor.  Hence, Atom was compiling the files a second time, every time I saved a file.

THE FIX: (tell atom-typescript to not compile)

change tsconfig.json to:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./app/js"
  },
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

all we did was add the "compileOnSave" option and set it to false.
Thus telling the atom compiler to not compile when saved.

NOTE** the files are still compiled on change due to tsc running concurrently with my lite-server.

Comment: This may be the solution to others whom started with the Angular2 Quickstart tutorial and have been trying to save the js files in a subfolder while using the Atom IDE.

Comment: Also, make sure to have`"compileOnSave": false` **after** `"compilerOptions"` otherwise it just won't work, as stated [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/atom-typescript-option-compileonsave-false-doesnt-work/24929/6)

Answer (score 0):

```
"outDir": "app/js"

"rootDir": "app/ts"
```

are each performing the compilation, remove `"outDir": "app/js"` and change rootDir to `"rootDir": "app/js"`

Comment: The result was that all of the js files were saved to /app/ts as well